# Not able to create/import project in Eclipse che

Tags: eclipse-che

[Logs File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvZ7O.png) I am trying to create simple java project from my practice on eclipse che which created using docker, but i am not able to create any project or import project after creating workspace.

1.I created container of eclipse che using docker

```
run -it --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /home/share:/data -e CHE_PORT=9092 -e CHE_SINGLE_PORT=true -t eclipse/che start
```

2. Then i created workspace taking java stack from listed options.
3. Once workspace is ready, then i am clicking on create project but after defining project name, create button is disabled to proceed further. Check screenshot
4. When I am trying to import project below error is coming

> 019/04/12 06:33:22 Error occurs on sending a ping message to WebSocket.
>   websocket: close sent 2019/04/12 06:33:22 Failed to send WebSocket
>   message: , due to occurred error websocket: close sent

Now i am stuck don't know how to proceed further.

[image: Create Project disabled image]

Comment: I've just checked project creation on codenvy.io and it goes well. Since there are not any project types on the left side of the panel I would guess Che didn't start well. If I could see Che logs I would say more.

Comment: @tolusha please see attached email for the logs , i have edited my post